# Blender 2.8 - Can't get weight painting to work as expected

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm trying to follow a weight rigging [tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/c8xocTFhvaw), everything works fine until I get to weight painting. I'm trying to "draw" over parts of the model but I don't understand the results. Maybe I'm not in the right mode or something.

To add to that - the display looks funny. In the tutorial, when you switch to weight painting there's a gradient between hot red to cold blue to indicate the armature weight over the model.

Here's how it looks on my machine:
[image]

And here's hot it looks in the tutorial:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I gonna be honest the paint in weight painting is a partial lie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I do it is.

1. go into edit mode
2. Select faces you want controlled
3. Select the shape key and assign the faces to it.

   [A quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNsLlnklwg0&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: What is the shape key? Also, this looks like a binary thing either assigned or not. How do you set partial control of an armature over a vertex?

Comment: @Barak There is now a video.